# Add swipe to delete UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am making a CheckList application with a `UITableView`. I was wondering how to add a swipe to delete a `UITableViewCell`.

This is my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,  UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,      UITableViewDataSource {

var tableView: UITableView!
var textField: UITextField!
var tableViewData:Array<String> = []

// Define Colors

let lightColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.996, green: 0.467, blue: 0.224, alpha: 1)
let medColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.973, green: 0.388, blue: 0.173, alpha: 1)
let darkColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.800, green: 0.263, blue: 0.106, alpha: 1)
let greenColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.251, green: 0.831, blue: 0.494, alpha: 1)

init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    // Custom initialization
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Set up table view

    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-100), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    self.tableView.registerClass(MyTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = darkColor
    //self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

    //Set up text field

    self.textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 100))
    self.textField.backgroundColor = lightColor
    self.textField.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Bold", size: 26)
    self.textField.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(self.textField)



}

//Table View Delegate

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return tableViewData.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

    var myNewCell: MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyTableViewCell
    myNewCell.text = self.tableViewData[indexPath.row]

    return myNewCell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

    let mySelectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    //Colors

    mySelectedCell.detailTextLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    mySelectedCell.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    //Setup Details / Date

    let myDate:NSDate = NSDate()
    var myDateFormatter:NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    myDateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle

    mySelectedCell.detailTextLabel.text = myDateFormatter.stringFromDate(myDate)
    mySelectedCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    mySelectedCell.backgroundColor = greenColor

}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true

}

//Text Field Delegate

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    tableViewData.append(textField.text)
    textField.text = ""
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}

}
```

And this is MyTableViewCell.swift:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

let medColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.973, green: 0.388, blue: 0.173, alpha: 1)

init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String) {
    super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.backgroundColor = medColor
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

I am using iOS8 as deployment target (not sure of the difference it will make).

Comment: Please read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS". There is a whole section on dealing with table view deletions. You are missing several required delegate methods to make it work.

Answer (score 352, accepted):

Add these two functions:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
    }
}
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
    }
}
```

**Swift 4.2**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
    }
}
```

Comment: Novice iOS programmer here - is there a good way to learn what methods need to be implemented for handling (seemingly) basic functionality like this? The documentation seems a bit verbose and hard to follow for my newbishnes.

Comment: A big notice! This is about to change in iOS8. Just heads up. `;)`

Comment: and how to change the "DELETE" button text?

Comment: @Dash does this answer work by itself or as an addition to the asker's code?

Comment: @rigdonmr these are to be added to the original code.

Comment: @datayeah  if you want to change "Delete" button text, you can do  override this function, **func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> String? {
        //return the text you want to add here
    }**

Comment: How do i Insert row one by one  from NSMutableArray by (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Insert)?

Comment: The swift 3 code is missing a closing curly bracket `}`. It took me 5 total minutes to figure out this :p

Comment: Doesn't need the "override" if it's in a UIViewController

Comment: @lase You might want to take a peek at an app called Dash. It enables you to search documentation and it's a lot snappier than browsing the web. It's also stored locally on your computer, so you don't need web access to look stuff up. You can also load up documentation for other languages.

Comment: Is it possible to make the same for section header? For example for delete all items in section.

Comment: Pretty sure the `UITableViewCell.EditingStyle` in your Swift 4.2 answer should actually be `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` (no `.`)

Comment: @lase the iOS API is filled with so many things that it would be practically impossible to know it all. So as cliche as it sounds, you learn stuff like this from experience. I have been doing iOS for 6 years and i am here just like you because i forgot how to add Swipe to Delete :^)

Comment: You no longer need to use first method in the latest Swift version.

Answer (score 33):

You can try this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            NamesTable.beginUpdates()
            Names.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            NamesTable.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: nil)
            NamesTable.endUpdates()

        }
}
```

If you're supporting iOS11+ please see the [discussion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614908-beginupdates):

> Use the [performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates) method instead of this one whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for `beingUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`. You don't see them often and I just saw they were part of the WWDC Best Practices talk.

Comment: Thank you for this!!  :D

Answer (score 27):

Another way that allows you to change the text of "Delete" and add more buttons when sliding a cell is to use `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: (UITableView!), commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: (NSIndexPath!)) {

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") {action in
       //handle delete
    }

    var editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") {action in
        //handle edit
    }

    return [deleteAction, editAction]
}
```

`canEditRowAtIndexPath` and `commitEditingStyle` are still required, but you can leave `commitEditingStyle` empty since deletion is handled in `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Had to change the signature of the last function to `    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?` but otherwise it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Crashalot if your class inherits from `UITableViewController` and you are overriding this method, then yes the signature must return `[UITableViewRowAction]?`. However, when you are not inheriting from `UITableViewController`, that is when the method should return `[AnyObject]?`. Thought I would clear up when to use which so anyone who reads this isn't just guessing.

Answer (score 24):

It's new feature in iOS11 and Swift 4.

[**Reference link :**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2018/01/table-swipe-actions-in-swift-4-using.html)

**Trailing Swipe :**

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
        print("index path of delete: \(indexPath)")
        completionHandler(true)
    }

    let rename = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
        print("index path of edit: \(indexPath)")
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    let swipeActionConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [rename, delete])
    swipeActionConfig.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return swipeActionConfig
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource
    {
      var items: String[] = ["We", "Heart", "Swift","omnamay shivay","om namay bhagwate vasudeva nama"]
        var cell : UITableViewCell
}




    @IBOutlet var tableview:UITableView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as? UITableViewCell

        if !cell {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")}



        cell!.textLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
        }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)


            if let tv=tableView
            {



             items.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
                tv.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)



        }
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 8):

use it :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        langData.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row) //langData is array from i delete values
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath],  withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }
}
```

hope it helps you

Answer (score 8):

I used tableViewCell to show multiple data, after swipe () right to left on a cell it will show two buttons Approve And reject, there are two methods, the first one is ApproveFunc which takes one argument, and the another one is RejectFunc which also takes one argument.
[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let Approve = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Approve") { action, index in

        self.ApproveFunc(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
    Approve.backgroundColor = .green

    let Reject = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Reject") { action, index in

        self.rejectFunc(indexPath: indexPath)
    }
    Reject.backgroundColor = .red



    return [Reject, Approve]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func ApproveFunc(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
func rejectFunc(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: 'UITableViewRowAction' is deprecated in iOS 13. You need to use 'UIContextualAction' instead!

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4 -- @available(iOS 11.0, *)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let edit = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "") { (action, view, nil) in
        let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Deletion", message: "Are you sure you want to remove this item from cart? ", preferredStyle: .alert)

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

        }))

        refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            refreshAlert .dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        self.present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    edit.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3215686275, green: 0.5960784314, blue: 0.2470588235, alpha: 1)
    edit.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "storyDelete")
    let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [edit])
    config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
    return config
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Xcode 6.1.1, there are some tiny changes to Dash's answer.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        // delete data and row
        dataList.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how I can change the delete button to say cancelled?

Comment: if you want to change "Delete" button text, you can do override this function, func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> String? { //return the text you want to add here } #Rachel

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3** with custom title supported

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
                return true
            }

    //If you want to change title
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String? {
                return "Cancel"
            }

            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
// you might want to delete the item at the array first before calling this function
                    tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPath, with: .automatic)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Works for me in Swift 2.0

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let block = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Block") { action, index in
        print("Block")
        self.removeObjectAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { action, index in
        print("Delete")
        self.removeObjectAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    return [delete, block]
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what `"Block"` does?

Answer (score 4):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: "DELETE"){(UITableViewRowAction,NSIndexPath) -> Void in

        print("What u want while Pressed delete")
    }
    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "EDIT"){(UITableViewRowAction,NSIndexPath) -> Void in

        print("What u want while Pressed Edit")
    }

    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    return [delete,edit]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 4 tableview add, swipe to delete UITableViewCell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath

    }
    return [delete]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

Since UITableViewRowAction was deprecated in iOS 13.0 so you can use UISwipeActionsConfiguration

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
            self.deleteData(at: indexPath)
        }

        let editAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") {  (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
            self.editData(at: indexPath)
        }
        editAction.backgroundColor = .purple
        let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction,editAction])

        return swipeActions
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func deleteData(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }

    func editData(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let action =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
                //do stuff
                completionHandler(true)
                let data:NSDictionary = self.conversations[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
                print(data)
                let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "are you sure want to delete ?", preferredStyle: .alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { (action) in
                }))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
            action.image = UIImage(named: "")
            action.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 148/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1.0)
            let confrigation = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])

            return confrigation
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        self.arrayFruit.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tblList.reloadData()
    }

    let edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.normal, title: "Edit") { (action, indexpath) in

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "FruitApp", message: "Enter Fuit Name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Enter new fruit name"
        })
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Update", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { [weak alert](_) in
            let textField = alert?.textFields![0]
            self.arrayFruit[indexPath.row] = (textField?.text!)!
            self.tblList.reloadData()
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    edit.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return [delete,edit]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For > ios 13
[image: tableViewCell swipe left to action]
[image: tableViewCell swipe right to action]
https://gist.github.com/andreconghau/de574bdbb468e001c404a7270017bef5#file-swipe_to_action_ios13-swift

```
/*
     SWIPE to Action
     */
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        return .none
    }
    // Right Swipe
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal,
                                        title: "Favourite") { [weak self] (action, view, completionHandler) in
                                            self?.handleMarkAsFavourite()
                                            completionHandler(true)
        }
        action.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                       trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        // Archive action
        let archive = UIContextualAction(style: .normal,
                                         title: "Archive") { [weak self] (action, view, completionHandler) in
                                            self?.handleMoveToArchive()
                                            completionHandler(true)
        }
        archive.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        // Trash action
        let trash = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive,
                                       title: "Trash") { [weak self] (action, view, completionHandler) in
            self?.handleMoveToTrash(book: (self?.books![indexPath.row]) as! BookItem)
                                        completionHandler(true)
        }
        trash.backgroundColor = .systemRed

        // Unread action
        let unread = UIContextualAction(style: .normal,
                                       title: "Mark as Unread") { [weak self] (action, view, completionHandler) in
                                        self?.handleMarkAsUnread()
                                        completionHandler(true)
        }
        unread.backgroundColor = .systemOrange

        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [trash, archive, unread])
        // If you do not want an action to run with a full swipe
        configuration.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
        return configuration
    }
    
    
    
    private func handleMarkAsFavourite() {
        print("Marked as favourite")
    }

    private func handleMarkAsUnread() {
        print("Marked as unread")
    }

    private func handleMoveToTrash(book: BookItem) {
        print("Moved to trash")
        print(book)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hi!", message: "Bạn có muốn xóa \(book.name)", preferredStyle: .alert)
            
             let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Xóa", style: .default, handler: { action in
                book.delete()
                self.listBook.reloadData()
             })
             alert.addAction(ok)
             let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Hủy", style: .default, handler: { action in
             })
             alert.addAction(cancel)
             DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                self.present(alert, animated: true)
        })
        
    }

    private func handleMoveToArchive() {
        print("Moved to archive")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 3 -- UIViewController

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
        print("delete tableview cell")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swift 3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {

        arrayCityName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.tableCityName.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add these
assuming your data array is 'data'

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)
        if let tv=table
        {



            data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tv.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)



        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

  let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Share") { action, index in
    //handle like delete button
    print("share button tapped")
  }

  share.backgroundColor = .lightGray

  let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Delete") { action, index in
    self.nameArray.remove(at: editActionsForRowAt.row)
    self.swipeTable.beginUpdates()
    self.swipeTable.deleteRows(at: [editActionsForRowAt], with: .right)
    self.swipeTable.endUpdates()

    print("delete button tapped")
  }

  delete.backgroundColor = .orange
  return [share,delete]
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
  return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

        let editAction = UIContextualAction.init(style: UIContextualAction.Style.normal, title: "Edit", handler: { (action, view, completion) in
            //TODO: Edit
            completion(true)
            self.popUpViewPresent(index:indexPath.row)
        })

        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction.init(style: UIContextualAction.Style.destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, view, completion) in
            //TODO: Delete
            completion(true)
            self.deleteTagAction(senderTag:indexPath.row)
        })
        editAction.image = UIImage(named: "Edit-white")
        deleteAction.image = UIImage(named: "Delete-white")
        editAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [deleteAction, editAction])
        config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
        return config
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode asks for UIContextualAction, here what worked for me for the updated version:

For Trailing Swipe Actions:->

```
 func delete(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
        let company = companies[indexPath.row]
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, _) in
           // Perform Delete Action
        }
        return action
    }
    
    func edit(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
        let action  = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, view, escaping) in
            // Perform Edit Action
        }
        return action
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let delete = self.delete(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        let edit = self.edit(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        let swipe = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, edit])
        return swipe
    }
```

For Leading Swipe Actions:->

```
 func delete(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
        let company = companies[indexPath.row]
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, _) in
           // Perform Delete Action
        }
        return action
    }
    
    func edit(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
        let action  = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, view, escaping) in
            // Perform Edit Action
        }
        return action
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let delete = self.delete(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        let edit = self.edit(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
        let swipe = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, edit])
        return swipe
    }
```

Return true for **canEditRowAt** for tableView Delegate:->

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```