# how to make a call when user swipe left in UITabelViewCell in iOS8 using swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am new to `swift` And programming. Please Anyone Help me for making call in `IOS8` using `UITabelViewCell` left swipe not to delete A Row but to make a call in iPhone using Swift language

Comment: What do you want to do when you swipe left ? Delete the row ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103069/swift-add-swipe-to-delete-tableviewcell

Comment: swipe left is not to delete the row  ,swipe left to make call in iPhone using swift

Comment: Search for information on implementing a UIPanGestureRecognizer in a cell and for opening TEL: URLs

Comment: Then it is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164188/custom-edit-view-in-uitableviewcell-while-swipe-left

No PanGestureRecognizers required

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a Delete or Insert button, you can use the following default functions of `UITableView` to accomplish that:

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}



// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
```

Although if you want a different custom button, you should have a look at `SWTableViewCell` at this link: https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

Comment: This question is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164188/custom-edit-view-in-uitableviewcell-while-swipe-left without use of custom frameworks.