# Implement a tablecell fade delete

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103069/swift-add-swipe-to-delete-uitableviewcell#24103137) to get that nice faded deleted cell. Currently when I swipe to delete, it's sharp, sudden and ugly. Other apps has that nice fade when cell is deleted.

In my app, the cell is not really deleted, the data is removed:

**Swift 3, func editingStyle:**

```
let tableSection = sections[sortedSections[indexPath.section]]
let tableItem = tableSection![indexPath.row]

// Removes item from array:
self.incomesDictionary.removeValue(forKey: tableItem.incomeId)

// Reloading the table data:
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

When I add `self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)` above the `...reloadData()` I get an error:

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

If I update the function with `tableSection?.remove(at: indexPath.row)`, it still crashes. Any tips to get that smooth effect?

**Edit:**

I have a programmatically grouped cell and the error I got, after adding the `.fade` is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 0, but there are only 0 sections before the update'

Comment: If you delete rows with `tableView.deleteRows...` you must not call `reloadData()` afterwards, only `deleteRows...` performs the animation.

Comment: @vadian  but the error is at "deleteRows..." Ok I'll remove the reload and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.0**

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-swipe-to-delete-uitableviewcells

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            self.myArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

This will prepare the tableView for your animation

Comment: Same :( Im not sure myself what's going on.

Comment: Here's the trace: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 0 from section 0, but there are only 0 sections before the update'`

Comment: Did you remove the value from your datasource as well?