# Not displaying the title in Swipe actions for UItableView Swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I have set an action for "add to cart" at leading side of the UItableViewCell. I have set background colour, its image and title. below's my code.

```
 @available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let addToCart = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Add to Cart") { (action, view, nil) in
        print("Added to cart")

    }
    addToCart.title = "Add to Cart"
    addToCart.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2196078449, green: 0.007843137719, blue: 0.8549019694, alpha: 1)
    addToCart.image = UIImage(named: "cart")

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [addToCart])
}
```

previous attempts : I have not defined title using `addToCart.title = "Add to Cart"` but, after not getting it, I have set that.

The image I have added is of 25*25 of size, has clear background and is of .png format.

[image]

Comment: you got any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **UIContextualAction** supports either **text** or **image**. By setting the image with setImage: property, basically remove the title when creating the object. If you want both text and image, you need to **create images with embedded text**.

its the bug in [UIContextualAction](https://github.com/lionheart/openradar-mirror/issues/17815). It does not show both image and title at the same time **unless the table view cell height is 91 points.** for more info you get [forums.apple](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86009)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for a solution, I found this one on Medium: https://forzfilm.medium.com/how-to-set-image-and-label-in-trailing-swipe-action-with-custom-font-ios11-4a49d4794669.
It turns out that you can render a UIView as an Image.

Note: the answer below is with `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration`, but it you can also use it with tableView since they both use `UIContextualAction`. And the cell height in the example is 80.

**Tested in XCode 14 with `UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration`:**

**SwipeLayout:**

```
private func swipeLayout(icon: String, text: String, size: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: size, weight: .regular, scale: .large)
        let img = UIImage(systemName: icon, withConfiguration: config)?.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)

        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 13, weight: .medium)
        label.textColor = .white
        label.text = text

        let tempView = UIStackView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: img!.size.width, height: img!.size.height))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        tempView.axis = .vertical
        tempView.alignment = .center
        tempView.spacing = 2
        imageView.image = img
        tempView.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        tempView.addArrangedSubview(label)

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: tempView.bounds)
        let image = renderer.image { rendererContext in
            tempView.layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
        return image
    }
```

**in `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationProvider`:**

```
// archive
let archiveHandler: UIContextualAction.Handler = { [weak self] action, view, completion in
     completion(true)
//   self?.updateSnapShot(animated: true)
}
let archiveAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil, handler: archiveHandler)
archiveAction.image = self.swipeLayout(icon: "archivebox.fill", text: "Archive", size: 16)
archiveAction.backgroundColor = .theme.arhiveRow
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

[Add swipe to delete UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103069/add-swipe-to-delete-uitableviewcell/48145688#48145688)

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
            let action =  UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "", handler: { (action,view,completionHandler ) in
                //do stuff
                completionHandler(true)
                let data:NSDictionary = self.conversations[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
                print(data)
                let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "are you sure want to delete ?", preferredStyle: .alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: { (action) in
                }))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
            action.image = UIImage(named: "")
            action.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 148/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1.0)
            let confrigation = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])

            return confrigation
        }
```

Comment: what if I don't want to delete the row?!

Comment: the questioner need the answer in `UIContextualAction supports both text and image`