# UITableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt image and title

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios11, uitableviewrowaction

in iOS 11 we have a feature in UITableView  trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt to get the swipe events. But when I try to reduce the height of the row the text disappears and only image remains.

Is there any way I can keep both? My cell height should be 60.0 and I need to show both image and title. It works for 84.0.
The image size is 30x30 for @2x and 60x60 for @3x

Below is my code

```
let contextItem = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Rename") { (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in

       //do something
    }
    contextItem.image = UIImage(named: "deleteIcon")
let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [contextItem])
```

Comment: you can't use both, instead of use image with text

Comment: for sample see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50578490/not-displaying-the-title-in-swipe-actions-for-uitableview-swift-4/50578710#50578710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in iOS 11 that it does not show both image and title at the same time unless the table view cell height is 91 points. for more info you get https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86009

UIContextualAction supports either text or image. By setting the image with setImage: property, basically remove the title when creating the object. If you want both text and image, you need to create images with embedded text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both if you render a view with your label and image as an image. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75865759/13302643