# Is there a way to know when a UITableViewCell is removed from UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm, rx-swift

I am showing a `UITableView` which is driven by [RxRealmDataSources](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealmDataSources).

I need to perform some actions when a row in the table gets deleted.

Is there a way such that whenever a row gets deleted from the table, a function gets called with the indexpath of the deleted row?

Edit -

The UI of a cell of the `UITableView` in my app depends on 2 things -

- A data object that is fetched from the realm db ( [info](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealmDataSources#binding-to-a-table-view) )
- The index position of the row

Whenever, a cell gets deleted, I need to update the UI of its next cell.

If the only way the db ever got updated was by the direct action of the user, then I could have used [`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614871-tableview) method to get the `indexPath` of the cell that should be deleted and update the UI of the next cell.

However, the db is synced to cloud and the db is binded to the table view so that I do not have control on when cells gets added or deleted. It is for this reason, I wanted to know if there is a way to know when a cell is removed from `UITableView`

Comment: How is the row being deleted from the table view?

Comment: @rmaddy Whenever, an object is added, modified or deleted from the realm db, it emits a new event containing the all the objects in the table. https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxRealmDataSources#binding-to-a-table-view has information on how the `UITableView` is driven by the observable

Comment: Can you explain what your going to do after delete the row?

Comment: @ktrkathir The UI for a row depends on 2 things, a data object fetched from db and the row position of the cell. After a row gets deleted, the UI of the next row needs to be updated. ( After a row gets deleted, I get the next row and call a method to update the UI )

Comment: If tableview sequence update of inserting and deleting and updation can use performBatchUpdates(_:completion:) https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/2887515-performbatchupdates

Answer (score 1):

Due to the reusability of cells in `UITableView`, cells are not actually deleted until the table itself is deallocated.

I might assume that by 'deleting' cell you mean cell disappearing from the screen. In this case the following function of `UITableViewDelegate` might help you (called when the cell is not visible any more):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: By 'deleting', I mean when the cell is removed from the tableview like when we swipe the cell to the left to remove it.  As you have pointed out, this function will get called when the cell disappers from the screen and not when it is removed from the tableview

Comment: Then you might want to look at `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath)`

Comment: I looked at `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath)`. I do not think this is the correct method for this. The thing is that the tableView is bound to a database which may change without any user interaction. So, I don't think this is the right way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you said:

> By 'deleting', I mean when the cell is removed from the tableview like when we swipe the cell to the left to remove it.

Since you tagged RxSwift, the solution is to use `itemDeleted` as in:

```
tableView.rx.itemDeleted
    .subscribe(onNext: { print("delete item at index path \($0) from your model.")})
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

If you aren't looking for an Rx solution, then your question is a dup of:

[Add swipe to delete UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103069/add-swipe-to-delete-uitableviewcell)

Comment: This code works if the user initiates the action to delete a row. Because the DB that is bound to the tableView may change due to some other reasons also, a row may get deleted even if user did not swipe the row to left to delete it. I was looking for a way to detect those deletions. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @iaaflaafc One day when you have more experience, you will recognize the folly of using the view to as if it's a model. If you don't maintain proper model-view separation, I feel sorry for whoever has to maintain your code (even if it's you.)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by subclassing the `UITableView` class and overriding the [`func deleteRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614960-deleterows) method.

Comment: Why are you doing this? This shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @rmaddy I have edited my original question and added details as to the reason why I asked the question. I was not able to find a better to do this.

Comment: Don't do this! Use `rx.itemDeleted` or `tableView(_:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement 1 delegate method of UITableView.

- trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt

It's easy to implement. This delegate method will be called twice, one when you swipe and again when you press to delete a row.

```
`enter code here`
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        
        let config =  UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [makeDeleteContextualAction(forRowAt: indexPath)])
        config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = true
        
        return config
    }
    
    private func makeDeleteContextualAction(forRowAt indexpath:IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
        
        let deleteAction = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: LocalizableConstants.constLS_global_delete()) { (action, swipeButtonView, completion) in
    
            let product = self.products[indexpath.row]
            if let quantity = product.vo_quantity(), let amount = product.vo_priceFide() {
                self.totalProducts -= Int(truncating: quantity)
                self.totalAmount -= amount.doubleValue * quantity.doubleValue
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.lbBasketNumber.text = String(self.totalProducts)
                self.lbTotalAmount.text = String(self.totalAmount)
            }
            
            self.products.remove(at: indexpath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexpath], with: .fade)
            
            if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                action.image = ImagesConstants.constIMG_XCA_mini_icon_red_trash()
                action.image?.withTintColor(ConstantsColor.const_COLOR_RED())
                action.backgroundColor = ConstantsColor.const_COLOR_WHITE()
            } else {
                action.title = LocalizableConstants.constLS_global_delete()
            }
            
            completion(true)
        }
        
        return deleteAction
    }
```